# On the proof of Freyd Adjoint Functor Theorem

Tags: category-theory

I have been struggling for a long time with the proof of this theorem, in the version you can read in "Handbook of categorical algebra, Vol.1", Borceux, at page 109.

**Definition 1** A functor $G:\mathscr{C}\longrightarrow\mathscr{D}$ is final when the following two conditions are satisfied for every category $\mathscr{A}$ and every functor $F:\mathscr{D}\longrightarrow\mathscr{A}$:

(1) if the limit $(L,(p_D)_{D\in\mathscr{D}})$ of $F$ exists, then $(L,(p_{GC})_{C\in\mathscr{C}})$ is the limit of $F\circ G$

(2) if the limit $(L,(q_C)_{C\in\mathscr{C}})$ of $F\circ G$ exists, then the limit of $F$ exists as well (and applying condition (1) it is given by $(L, (p_D)_{D\in\mathscr{D}})$ with $p_{GC}=q_C$ for every $C\in\mathscr{C}$).

Equivalently, $G$ is final when for every functor $F:\mathscr{D}\longrightarrow\mathscr{A}$, the limit of $F$ exist if and only if the limit of $F\circ G$ exists, and these limits are equal.

**Definition 2** Let $F:\mathscr{A}\longrightarrow\mathscr{B}$ be a functor and $B$ an object of $\mathscr{B}$. The category $\varepsilon_B$ of elements of the functor $\mathscr{B}(B,F-):\mathscr{A}\longrightarrow Set$ is by definition the category with:

objects: $\langle A,b\rangle$ with $A\in\mathscr{A}$ and $b:B\longrightarrow FA$.

morphisms: $f:\langle A,b\rangle\longrightarrow\langle A',b'\rangle$ is an $\mathscr{A}$-morphism $f:A\longrightarrow A'$ such that $Ff\circ b=b'$.

**Definition 3** A functor $F:\mathscr{A}\longrightarrow\mathscr{B}$ satisfies the solution set condition with respect to the object $B$ of $\mathscr{B}$ when there exists a set $S_B\subseteq$ Obj($\mathscr{A}$) such that: $\forall A\in\mathscr{A} \ \ \ \forall b:B\longrightarrow FA \ \ \ \exists A'\in S_B\ \ \ \exists a:A'\longrightarrow A\ \ \ \exists b':B\longrightarrow FA'$ such that $F(a)\circ b'=b$.

**THEOREM** Consider a complete category $\mathscr{A}$ and a functor $F:\mathscr{A}\longrightarrow\mathscr{B}$. The following conditions are equivalent:

(1) $F$ has a left adjoint functor.

(2) The following conditions hold:

$\ \ \ (a) F$ preserves small limits

$\ \ \ (b) F$ satisfies the solution set condition for every $B\in\mathscr{B}$.

**proof** (1) implies (2) because every right adjoint preserves limits and because having a left adjoint is a stronger condition than satisfying the solution set condition. Conversely, consider the full subcategory $\mathscr{S}_B$ of $\varepsilon_B$ whose objects are the pairs $(A,b)$ with $A\in S_B$. This category is small. To conclude the proof it suffices to show that the inclusion $\mathscr{S}_B\subseteq\varepsilon_B$ is a final functor [then the proof of this fact follows...]

My questions are:

(1) Why is the fact that $\mathscr{S}_B\subseteq\varepsilon_B$ is final  sufficient to conclude this?

(2) Why is the fact that $\mathscr{S}_B$ is small relevant?

Comment: Smallness is important because you only know about limits of small diagrams.

Comment: @ZhenLin But Borcuex uses "complete" for saying "small-complete". I think he does not consider at all large limits.

Comment: Sure. That is why the solution set is supposed to be small.

Comment: Have you applied Proposition 3.3.1?

Comment: @KevinCarlson Suppose I can prove that $F\circ\Phi_B\circ i$ ($i$ is the inclusion of $\mathscr{S}_B$ in $\varepsilon_B$) has a limit. Then, being the inclusion a final functor, I deduce that $\Phi_B$ has a limit which is preserved by $F$ and 3.3.1 concludes the proof. The problem is that I can't prove that $F\circ\Phi_B\circ i$ has a limit.

Comment: If $(L,\lambda)$ is the limit of $\Phi_B\circ i$ guaranteed by completeness then $(FL,F\lambda)$ is a limit of $F\circ\Phi_B\circ i$ and by finality must extend to a limit of $F\circ\Phi_B$.

Comment: @KevinCarlson Sure, thank you very much.